# Unable to send mail from SSIS using script task - time out

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have created SSIS package using loop. This package exports 2 files (one pdf, one xlsx) from Reporting Services.

[image]

Generally, In the "script task" which sends exported files via outlook takes time out error. I looked but I can not figured it out, i am not an export about c#.

Error Desc. ;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operasyion has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage) .......

[image]

My Code;

```
#region Help:  Introduction to the script task

#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts;
#endregion

namespace ST_01aa093042ba46959a419d75a80d117c
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain :
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
                string fromString = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Email_From"].Value;
                string toString = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Email_TO"].Value;
                string ccString = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Email_CC"].Value;
                string attachmentName = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pdf_Send_Path"].Value;
                string attachmentName1 = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Excel_Send_Path"].Value;
                string emailBody = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Email_Body"].Value;


                mail.From = new MailAddress(fromString);

                mail.To.Add(toString);
                mail.CC.Add(ccString);

                mail.Subject = (String)Dts.Variables["User::Email_Subject"].Value;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentName));
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentName1));

                mail.Body = emailBody;

                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com.tr", "1111");
                SmtpServer.Timeout = 100000;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
                  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                Dts.Variables["User::Error_Value"].Value = 1;
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }


        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: can you ping smtp.office365.com on port 587 from the server SSIS runs on? might be a firewall issue.

Comment: @MitchWheat, ping is succesfull (using telnet), also firewall is down.

Comment: Does your organization have SMTP AUTH enabled? Have a read through [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Microsoft 365 or Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Actually it works well in normal etl period. But, It takes time out error when etl process takes longer then usual.   So i have to restart server after that i can run package successfully. It is so weird, i think i little trick may solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because of your files' size. If they are more than 600 mb I guess, you'll get error. check the size of files at first.

Comment: "Export and mail send" container loop has 16 rows. Loop process exports 1 excel file, 1 pdf file and sends 2 file for each row.  Size of all exported files (16 excel, 16 pdf ) is 10mb in total. Did you check "mail send" c# code? May be, i missed some code etc. i can not figure it out.